# `org.bson.codecs.configuration.CodecConfigurationException` when writing to MongoDB from vertx

Tags: vert.x, mongodb-java

I have a public `Connection` class that extends `JsonObject`. To store `Connection` objects I have the following static method:

```
  public static Future<Void> storeConnection(MongoClient mc, Connection cnx) {
    Future<Void> fut = Future.future();
    mc.save("coll", cnx, ar -> {
        if(ar.succeeded()) {
          fut.complete();
        }
        else {
          fut.fail(ar.cause());
        }
      });
    return fut;
  }
```

When calling `mc.save("coll", cnx, ar -> {...})` I get the exception `org.bson.codecs.configuration.CodecConfigurationException`. I tried some (obviously useless) things like changing the signature to have `cnx` being a `JsonObject`, casting `cnx` into a `JsonObject` or even creating a `JsonObject toJsonObject() { return (JsonObject)this; }` method. I got the same exception.

Yet, when I replace `mc.save("coll", cnx, ar -> {...})` with `mc.save("coll", new JsonObject().put("foo", "bar"), ar -> {...})`, the writing is successful.

I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

**Update**: I changed inheritance by composition:

```
public class Connection {
  private JsonObject data;
  ...
  // and then 
 public JsonObject jsonObject() { return data; }
  ...
}
```

and then `mc.save("coll", cnx.jsonObject(), ar -> { ... });` doesn't complain any more.

Yet, I don't get what was wrong with the inheritance case.